# How to terminate long running Hangfire job upon IIS app pool restart

Tags: .net, iis, hangfire

We are using Hangfire to enqueue a long running background job from a .NET application in IIS. This long running background job listens to Azure service bus and processes the message using a function in the same application. When we change the function and re-deploy the site in IIS, it creates another background job with updated code, **however**, the previous background job also keeps running with old code. How can we ensure that the old hangfire job is terminated when we deploy new code?

Comment: If your hangfire is deployed on iis, then you just need to stop the application pool of the website where it is located, if not, then this is a hangfire problem.